# Stanford CS 106B error when adding to vector of structs —issue with compiler?

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I'm trying to follow along with Stanford's CS 106B class online, but I'm hitting a wall when I try to add elements to a vector of structs. Any idea what's going on?

```
   struct point {                  // Definition for our "point" structure
    int x;
    int y;
    };

Vector<point> pointVector;

point derp;
derp.x = 1;
derp.y = 2;
pointVector.add(derp);
```

Unfortunately, when I try this I get two errors in XCode. The first one is "Template argument uses local type 'point.'" The second is "Request for member 'add' in 'pointVector', which is of non-class type 'int.' Is this some kind of problem with my compiler? Judging from the documentation, this should work.

Comment: There is no `Vector` in standard C++. Did you mean `std::vector`, or are you using a custom container?

Comment: Can you post the actual code ? You have to do assignments in a (member) function.

Comment: Does `Vector` exist, or did you mistake it for `std::vector`? Are you perhaps doing this inside a function?

Comment: @larsmans and K-ballo — it's the Vector class that's part of the CS 106B libraries. In the header Vector.h.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before 2011, the language had a bizarre and pointless restriction: template arguments could not involve local types. This has been fixed in the 2011 standard.

To fix the first error, either:

- Move the definition of `point` out of the function, into a class or namespace; or
- Enable C++11 support in your compiler, or get a more up-to-date compiler if it can't do that.

The second error is a knock-on effect of the first; the compiler failed to determine the type of `pointVector`, so it unhelpfully decided to pretend it was `int` and carry on. The error should go away once you've fixed the first one.

Answer (score -1):

Try to do

```
typedef struct point {                  // Definition for our "point" structure
    int x;
    int y;
}point;

std::vector<point> pointVector;

point derp;
derp.x = 1;
derp.y = 2;
pointVector.add(derp);
```

or

```
struct point {                  // Definition for our "point" structure
    int x;
    int y;
    };

std::vector<struct point> pointVector;

point derp;
derp.x = 1;
derp.y = 2;
pointVector.add(derp);
```

This should do it.

Comment: `typedef` for `struct` is unnecessary. There is no need to use the keyword `struct` with it's types.

Comment: There is no `std::Vector` either.

Comment: `std::vector` doesn't have an `add()` method, so it looks like OP is using a different `Vector` class. In any case, that is not the reason behind the error. You also have some unnecessary `structs` and `typedefs` in your sample code.